# Disabling syslogd in FreeBSD

Tags: freebsd, daemon, syslogd

I'm running FreeBSD in a very small VM with about 1.5G of space. I'd like to disable `syslogd` to save disk space, but there is no entry for it in `/etc/rc.conf`. `service -e` shows that `syslogd` is indeed running. How do I disable/uninstall it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Stop the daemon:

```
/etc/rc.d/syslogd stop
```

Append a line to the `/etc/rc.conf`:

```
syslogd_enable="NO"
```

Answer (score 3):

Igor's answer is good but I'd like to expand on it for current and future search engine guests. To **completely** disable syslogd, a little bit more is necessary:

### Completely disable syslogd

#### stop syslogd

`service syslogd onestop`

- Uses the `service` command which has been with us since FreeBSD 7.3 (2012). It works for services in /etc/rc.d as well as /usr/local/etc/rc.d and is more finger friendly.
- Using `onestop` instead of `stop` will stop syslogd even if these commands are run out of order.

#### disable syslogd

`sysrc syslogd_enable=NO`

That command does exactly what Igor instructs and appends a line to /etc/rc.conf which prevents syslogd from starting in the future. Sysrc appeared in FreeBSD 9.2 (2015). Previously, the same thing was usually accomplished with `echo syslogd_enable=NO >> /etc/rc.conf`.

#### disable newsyslog at boot

`sysrc newsyslog_enable=NO`

This command prevents `newsyslog` from running at boot time.

#### disable newsyslog at run time

`sed -i .bak -e '/^0.*newsyslog/ s/^0/#0/' /etc/crontab`

This sed command searches for the line that starts with a 0 and contains the word newsyslog. Then it inserts a # in front of the zero, disabling the newsyslog cron task. Now you won't get pesky emails from cron complaining that:

> newsyslog: pid file doesn't exist: /var/run/syslog.pid

---

### Is disabling syslogd a good idea?

EhevuTov makes a very good point that disabling syslogd to save disk space is probably not the best reasoning. However, there are some very good reasons one might want to disable syslogd.

1. Running FreeBSD in a jail with a process that handles its own logging (squid, nginx, etc.). If nothing in the jail uses syslogd, there's no gain in having it running.
2. Running thousands of jails on a FreeBSD host might make a different syslog architecture more sane (dropping log sockets into each jail (see syslogd -l)).
3. No. 2 holds even for handfuls of jails when centralized logging is desired. It avoids needing every jail configured with `@host` syntax for forwarding.
4. Numbers 2 & 3 are *especially* significant if you are also routing all the logs to external systems for indexing and archival. Syslog forwarding ends up making those use cases more complicated.
5. Using a different syslog daemon. If using an alternate syslog daemon, there's a good chance you want FreeBSD's stock syslog and all its assumptions and expectations **completely** disabled.

Answer (score 2):

Append a line to the `/etc/rc.conf`:

> syslogd_enable="NO"

Stop the daemon:

> /etc/rc.d/syslogd stop

However, I wouldn't recommend stopping syslogd. I recommend instead editing the size and frequency of your log rotation by editing your `/etc/newsyslog.conf` configuration file. It's very modifiable. You can comment out the services you don't want to follow with a `#` in the front of the row, or modify the:

- `count` for max number of file archives
- `size` for the size of each archive
- `when` for when you want to rotate

There are a bunch of options that I would think could fit your situation. For instance, if you want to only keep a max kb size for your logs, you can do that. Surely you could spare a few kb for logs :-P Read the `man newsyslog.conf` for more detail on grooming the log system size you want.